Measure in PowerBI not displaying title for pie chart properly when there is no data
I have bookmark page, “Sourcing area pie chart”, that has pie charts for all sourcing areas in our system. All the pie charts are filtered per sourcing area under “Filters” for the visuals. I have a measure that is dynamically adjusted.
For example if we have a pie chart filtered for sourcing area Y,
The user selects growing season X and there is data for Y in growing season X, then the title should show,
“Input cost % for Y in X” – case A
and in the case that there is no data for Y in growing season X it should show,
“No data available for Y” – case B
However, currently the measure only works with case A, and case B not. The issue seems to stem from if there is data for a sourcing area for a specific growing season. If there is, the measure works as intended, if there isn’t it does not work.
I am not sure what the issue is and how to fix it. I have made sure the slicer for sourcing is not affecting the pie chart, but the issue persists.
Measure used:
_SourcingareaPietitle =

IF(
    ISBLANK(MAX('CAD$,T,Ha'[Growing Season])) || 
    ISBLANK(SELECTEDVALUE('CAD$,T,Ha'[Delivery period])) || 
    ISBLANK(SELECTEDVALUE('CAD$,T,Ha'[DataType])), 
    "No data available for " & 
    SELECTEDVALUE('CAD$,T,Ha'[Sourcing Area], MAX('CAD$,T,Ha'[Sourcing Area])), 
    "Input cost % for " & 
    SELECTEDVALUE('CAD$,T,Ha'[Sourcing Area], MAX('CAD$,T,Ha'[Sourcing Area])) & 
    " in " & 
    MAX('CAD$,T,Ha'[Growing Season])
)



I think you have a problem with the filtering context and how ISBLANK interacts with your model specifically, if no rows exist in the table for the given filtering combination, the measure may not evaluate as expected so you may try the below :
_SourcingareaPietitle = 
IF(
    ISBLANK(
        CALCULATE(
            MAX('CAD$,T,Ha'[Growing Season]),
            REMOVEFILTERS('CAD$,T,Ha')
        )
    ),
    "No data available for " & 
    SELECTEDVALUE('CAD$,T,Ha'[Sourcing Area], MAX('CAD$,T,Ha'[Sourcing Area])),
    "Input cost % for " & 
    SELECTEDVALUE('CAD$,T,Ha'[Sourcing Area], MAX('CAD$,T,Ha'[Sourcing Area])) & 
    " in " & 
    MAX('CAD$,T,Ha'[Growing Season])
)


Thank you for the suggestion. However, now it resulted in it simply saying "Input cost % for ".
I do think that you are correct about where the issue stems from. As the visual filter is set on a specific sourcing area, if there is no data for that specific year the visual filter displays this as such,
" [Selected sourcing area] (0)"
And that is the issue I believe.

Can you please provide your model and some data ?

Sorry confidential data ;/

It is ok you can provide dummy data. Help us to help uou :)

The main table used is 'CAD$,T,Ha' . It contains a number of columns, but the important ones in this case are, [Region], [Sourcing Area], [Growing Season], [Data Type] and [Total Input Cost].
The [Total Input Cost] is a summation of several input and their cost related to the production, for example [Fertilizer] and [Pesticide].
The Piecharts are designed and visually filtered so that they show the % share of each input on the Total Input Cost.
Does it answer your question?
